# Question on Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Taylor's Theorem
>
> Let $\{c_n\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers.
>
> Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum c_n z^n$.
>
> Let $|b|<R$ and $f(x)=\sum c_n z^n$ on the disk $B(0,R)$.
>
> Then, $\forall |x-b|<R-|b|, f(x)=\sum d_n (x-b)^n$ for some sequence $\{d_n\}$.

In the situation illustrated above, is $R-|b|$ the raius of convergence of $\sum d_n z^n$?

Comment: What do you notice if you draw the region of convergence of $\sum c_n z^n$ and the disc $\{|x - b| < R - |b|\}$?

Comment: @Travis Circle inside a circle and boundaries meet at a point. Does this tell anything about the radius of $\sum d_n z^n$? Can the radius be bigger so that two boundaries meet at two points?

Comment: What do you know about the function given by a converging power series on (the interior of) its disk of convergence?

Comment: @Travis It's uniformly convergent on $B(0,R-\epsilon)$ and is infinitely differentiable on $B(0,R)$. I'm sure I understand this concept well enough. However, since $\{c_n\}$ and $\{d_n\}$ are *different* sequences, these give different radius of convergence. I'm asking whether the radius of $\{d_n\}$ is $R-|b|$, and I really do believe it is not necessarily.

Comment: @Travis So is the radius of convergence of $\sum d_n z^n$ exactly $R-|b|$ or greater than this? Is there any counterexample?

Comment: Yes, it's infinitely differentiable and so analytic on $B(0, R)$. What do you know about the radius of convergence of analytic functions?

Comment: It may be greater than that. For example, the radius of convergence of the series for $1/(1 - z)$ about $0$ is $R = 1$, but the radius for the series expanded around $-\frac{1}{2} \in B(0, 1)$ is $\frac{3}{2} > 1 - |\frac{1}{2}|$.

Comment: @Travis Would you please ask me directly? I'm sorry that I really don't get you. I think it doesn't make sense to say "the radius of convergence of **analytic** function". Consider a Gamma function. Radius of Taylor expasion of the Gamma function depends on a point

Comment: Of course I mean radius (with a given base point). The function $\sum c_n z^n$ converges to some analytic function $f$ on $B(0, R)$. Now, you're observed that $\{|x - b| < R - |b|\} \subset B(0, R)$; what happens when you expand $f$ in a power series about $b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be larger. Take for instance $f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$. The radius of convergence at $0$ is $1$. The radius of convergence at $b=3/4$ is $5/4$, larger than $1/4$. Note that $5/4$ is the distance form $3/4$ to the set $\{i, -i\}$, the singular points of $f$.